# Heroku build django app doesn't create STATIC_ROOT dir if DEBUG=False. Why, what goes up in there?

Tags: django, heroku, build, django-staticfiles

Dajango (+channels/postgres/redis) app on heroku with DEBUG=True works well, no errors, no abnormalities. If DEBUG=False then it actually doesn't work at all, error500. Some clue how DEBUG flag can be involved in a way like that?  Thank you.

Heroku Log Example, DEBUG=True (works OK):

GET path="/"

"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302

"GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200

```
2020-07-23T16:14:24.496575+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=immense-escarpment-72885.herokuapp.com request_id=78bccd24-e86e-481f-995e-0aa31b2e440d fwd="68.14.159.220" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=117ms status=302 bytes=240 protocol=https
2020-07-23T16:14:24.495692+00:00 app[web.1]: 68.14.159.220:0 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302
2020-07-23T16:14:24.705467+00:00 app[web.1]: 68.14.159.220:0 - "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 200
```

login page is displayed, OK.

Now the problem: only difference is DEBUG=False:

GET path="/"

UserWarning: No directory at: /app/pickupteaming/staticfiles/

"GET / HTTP/1.1" 302

"GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 500

Heroku Log Example detailed below:

```
2020-07-23T16:17:32.649059+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=immense-escarpment-72885.herokuapp.com request_id=22b8a783-04e8-4fda-a185-f0f39c69125e fwd="68.14.159.220" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=125ms status=302 bytes=240 protocol=https
2020-07-23T16:17:32.527579+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py:116: UserWarning: No directory at: /app/pickupteaming/staticfiles/
2020-07-23T16:17:32.527606+00:00 app[web.1]: warnings.warn(u"No directory at: {}".format(root))
2020-07-23T16:17:32.643881+00:00 app[web.1]: 68.14.159.220:0 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302
2020-07-23T16:17:32.733941+00:00 app[web.1]: 68.14.159.220:0 - "GET /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 500
2020-07-23T16:17:32.739475+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/accounts/login/?next=/" host=immense-escarpment-72885.herokuapp.com request_id=991497fb-57f9-42f6-ae6b-c4a85dcdc79c fwd="68.14.159.220" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=60ms status=500 bytes=353 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set DEBUG=FALSE you are setting into production mode and Django won't serve your static file the same way like in development mode, as it is inefficient and insecure. You need to install WhiteNoise and do some ajustments on your setting.py file. Check this excellent guide by [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment#Serving_static_files_in_production)